# Adding macro to Add-ins tab Custom Toolbars?

Tags: excel, vba

I just finished a VBA project, and now I want to add a button for it in the Add-ins tab. I inherited an existing toolbar, so I'll need to incorporate my button into it; [here's what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfPOs.png). I have the .xlam file for the existing macros in the Toolbar.

In my project, I added a module that calls all of the macros I want to run in the button. I'm not sure if this is a necessary step, but [here's what I've done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pwb0.png). I also downloaded my macros as a .xlam file and .bas files.

I've found plenty of resources for adding a macro button to the Quick Access Toolbar and Developer tab, but that's not what I need to achieve. Any hints or links on how to add the macro to the Add-ins tab?

Here is the `CommandBar` and `msoControl` code:

```
Sub MyCB()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars(sCB).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application.CommandBars.Add(sCB, , False, True)

        With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "Compound"
            .Caption = "Compound Summary"
            .TooltipText = "Create Compound Summary"
            .OnAction = "CreateSummaryReport"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With

       With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "HPLC Stability Timetable"
            .Caption = "HPLC Stability Timetable"
            .TooltipText = "Create HPLC Stability Timetable"
            .OnAction = "STBLIncubationTime"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With

       With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "Well Sorting"
            .Caption = "Well Sorting"
            .TooltipText = "Sort Data Submissions"
            .OnAction = "WellSorter"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With


       With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "CLND Data Preparation"
            .Caption = "CLND Data Preparation"
            .TooltipText = "Formats and copies CLND data for transfer to YTD"
            .OnAction = "CLNDdecider"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With

       With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "Grav. Caff. YTD Dump"
            .Caption = "Grav. Caff. YTD Dump"
            .TooltipText = "Dumps grav. caff. data into YTD"
            .OnAction = "gravcafffinder"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With

       With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "Array Assay Platemap to CSV"
            .Caption = "Array Assay Platemap to CSV"
            .TooltipText = "Converts Array assay platemaps to CSVs"
            .OnAction = "AssayPlatemapToCSV"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With

       With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "Array Submission Setup"
            .Caption = "Array Submission Setup"
            .TooltipText = "Performs initial setup for Array submission file"
            .OnAction = "ArraySubmissionWorksheet"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With

       With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "Array Cal. Platemap to CSV"
            .Caption = "Array Cal. Platemap to CSV"
            .TooltipText = "Converts Array calibration platemaps to CSVs"
            .OnAction = "CalPlatemapToCSV"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With

       With .Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
            .Tag = "ElogD Report Formatting"
            .Caption = "ElogD Report Formatting"
            .TooltipText = "Formats ElogD Table for Reporting"
            .OnAction = "ElogDreportformat"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
       End With

        .Protection = msoBarNoCustomize
        .Position = msoBarTop
        .RowIndex = msoBarRowLast
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In the "pre-ribbon" days you could add custom menu items to the old-style menus using VBA.  Post-ribbon that same code ends up adding buttons on the "Add-ins" tab. That seems to be what you have in your screenshot. So you need to locate (and preferably post as text, not a picture) the code that creates the existing menu items you show in your first screenshot.  Search your add-in code for terms like "CommandBar" and "msoControl" to find what you need to modify.

Comment: You're looking for `CommandBar` code, like Tim said. Suggestion: look into Custom Ribbon UI, looks much better =)

Comment: @TimWilliams and @MathieuGuindon Thank you! I'll start rooting though the inherited code to find ```CommandBar```

Comment: @TimWilliams and @MathieuGuindon Ok I found the inherited ```CommandBar``` and ```msoControl``` code. I edited my post to include it.

Comment: Resolved! I added my successfully added my button to the Toolbar.

Comment: Congrats.  That tab might be more usable if you organize those items in a single drop-down, so there's no left-right scrolling...

Comment: @TimWilliams That's a great idea, do you know of a link that shows how to do that? Or if you give me some key words I can look into it myself. Btw, I think you've responded to multiple questions of mine in the past; I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to create a drop-down menu instead of a bunch of buttons

```
Const MENU_NAME As String = "Lab Tools"

Sub CreateMenuTest()
    Dim menu As CommandBarPopup
    Dim menuItem As Object, opt As Object

    Set menu = Application.CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, _
                    before:=HelpPos(), temporary:=True)
    menu.Caption = MENU_NAME

    Set menuItem = menu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    menuItem.Caption = "Do Something"
    menuItem.OnAction = "DoSomething"

    Set menuItem = menu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    menuItem.Caption = "Do Another Thing"
    menuItem.OnAction = "DoAnother thing"

    'start a sub-menu
    Set menuItem = menu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    menuItem.Caption = "Options..."

    Set opt = menuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    opt.Caption = "Option A"
    opt.OnAction = "DoActionA"

    Set opt = menuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    opt.Caption = "Option B"
    opt.OnAction = "DoActionB"

End Sub

Sub RemoveMenuTest()
    Application.CommandBars(1).Controls(MENU_NAME).Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! I'll try it out.